# How can I check if a value is nan or a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm currently working with pandas `DataFrame`s.
While iterating over it I want to check if a value is `numpy.nan` or a list.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
value = row["Name"]
if pd.isnull(value):
    dosomething()
```

This works just fine, except if

```
type(value) == list
```

Then I thought of maybe putting `any()` around:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
value = row["Name"]
if any(pd.isnull(value)):
    dosomething()
```

But now I get a exception everytime a `NaN` is in value because it's obviously not iterable.

Is there a better solution then checking the type of value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `or`:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    value = row["Name"]
    if pd.isnull(value) or (type(value) == list):
        dosomething()
```

Another way for check is `isinstance`:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    value = row["Name"]
    if pd.isnull(value) or isinstance(value, list):
        dosomething()
```

Comment: But I still get an errormessage if type(value)==list (ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all())

Comment: @aAnnAa - Maybe duplicated columns, then need `any(pd.isnull(value) or (type(value) == list))`

Comment: It works now with "if not isinstance(value, list) and pd.isnull(value)", thanks a lot for your help :)